# AppCompatButton Styling Issues on Some Devices

Tags: android, xml

I have this button on my xml, that is being styled:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/start_learning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Start Learning"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button.Next" />
```

here is the Stylein `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button.Next" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">

    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/digital_green</item>

</style>
```

When I build, it works well on most devices I have tested on. On a Techno Tab 5.1, This does not render's well. The button is not styled.

Comment: What about `style="@style/..."` instead of `app:theme="@style/"`?

Comment: @azizbekian , still did not work